# Calculating logLik by hand from a logistic regression

Tags: r, regression, glm, genetic

I ran a mixed model logistic regression adjusting my model with genetic relationship matrix using an R package known as `GMMAT` (function: `glmmkin()`).

My output from the model includes (taken from the user manual):

- `theta`: the dispersion parameter estimate [1] and the variance component parameter estimate [2]
- `coefficients`: fixed effects parameter estimates (including the intercept).
- `linear.predictors`: the linear predictors.
- `fitted.values`: fitted mean values on the original scale.
- `Y`: a vector of length equal to the sample size for the final working vector.
- `P`: the projection matrix with dimensions equal to the sample size.
- `residuals`: residuals on the original scale. NOT rescaled by the dispersion parameter.
- `cov`: covariance matrix for the fixed effects (including the intercept).
- `converged`: a logical indicator for convergence.

I am trying to obtain the log-likelihood in order to compute variance explained. My first instinct was to pull apart the `logLik.glm` function in order to compute this "by hand" and I got stuck at trying to compute AIC. I used the answer from [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/87345/calculating-aic-by-hand-in-r).

I did a sanity check with a logistic regression run with `stats::glm()` where the `model1$aic` is 4013.232 but using the Stack Overflow answer I found, I obtained 30613.03.

My question is -- does anyone know how to compute log likelihood from a logistic regression by hand using the output that I have listed above in R?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No statistical insight here, just the solution I see from looking at `glm.fit`. This only works if you did not specify weights while fitting the models (or if you did, you would need to include those weights in the model object)

```
get_logLik <- function(s_model, family = binomial(logit)) {
    n <- length(s_model$y)
    wt <- rep(1, n) # or s_model$prior_weights if field exists
    deviance <- sum(family$dev.resids(s_model$y, s_model$fitted.values, wt))
    mod_rank <- sum(!is.na(s_model$coefficients)) # or s_model$rank if field exists

    aic <- family$aic(s_model$y, rep(1, n), s_model$fitted.values, wt, deviance) + 2 * mod_rank
    log_lik <- mod_rank - aic/2
    return(log_lik)
}
```

For example...

```
model <- glm(vs ~ mpg, mtcars, family = binomial(logit))
logLik(model)
# 'log Lik.' -12.76667 (df=2)

sparse_model <- model[c("theta", "coefficients", "linear.predictors", "fitted.values", "y", "P", "residuals", "cov", "converged")]
get_logLik(sparse_model)
#[1] -12.76667
```